# CAML query regex

Tags: 2013, caml-query, caml, regex

is there a way to perform **regex query with CAML**? 
I have a string field (Display) composed by Name and Surname. 
I have a single search input.

I wish to have these results `*Display* match UserInput`

How can I do it with CAML?

Comment: Display is your custom field of type string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use regex query with CAML.

The closest thing you will get to wildcard searching and CAML is using either the BeginsWith or the Contains element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196501.aspx

So the only thing you are missing then is an EndsWith.

In regards to dates make sure you format your dates as "yyyy-MM-dd-Thh:mm:ssZ" and all should work.